# How do I move all the files with the same name scattered through the file system into one folder?

Tags: command-line, filesystems, find

I have a file system tree and on different locations within it are files with the same name. I tried the following command on the command line:

```
find / -name "HAHA" -exec mv {} /home \;
```

It only worked for one file, for the others I received an error message for having the same name.

Can I change the command in a way that for each file name a number will be attached to distinguish them?

[image]

Comment: If you don't need to keep the original name, you can always offload the action to a script that does something like `mv "$0" /home/$(uuidgen)` to give each file a new, unique name. Would such a solution be acceptable?

Comment: sorry, I do not understand $0 and $(uuidgen)

Comment: I tried to create a function to be given to `find` but it did not accept it.  Creating a script worked but that did not allow the number to be incremented.  I am interested in the solution myself now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a simple solution with a small script.  The script is called `cpf` (or whatever name you give it) and is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=xyz       # Directory where you want the files
num=1

for file in "$@"
do
    base=`basename -- "$file"`
    mv -- "$file" "$dir/$base.$num"
    num=$(($num+1))
done
```

You execute the command as follows:

```
find . -name HAHA -print0 | xargs -0x cpf
```

Comment: Using `xargs -x` is _highly_ recommended here. Otherwise, xargs might silently decide it would like to start several sequencial `cpf` processes, each of which would have their own counter and start overwriting the haha's already moved.

Comment: Or just remove `xargs` entirely and pipe the filenames to `cpf` (and modify `cpf` to read them from standard input)

Answer (score 11):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. If you have installed `mv` from [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (which probably is the case), then the following command...

   ```
   find / -name "HAHA" -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered "{}" /home \;
   ```

   ...will move all files called `HAHA` to `/home`. The `--backup=numbered` [option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Backup-options.html#Backup-options) of `mv` ensures that every time the `mv` command executes, it will check if there already exists a file named `HAHA` in the target directory -- and if it does, then it first renames it to `HAHA.~n~` (where `n` is an increasing number) before moving the new file to the `/home`. In the end, you will end up with files named like `HAHA`, `HAHA.~1~`, `HAHA.~2~` etc. in `/home`.
2. This shell script should do the trick, but it is not resistant against paths containing newlines:

   ```
   IFS="
   "      # if you are using bash, you can just use IFS=$'\n' here
   i=1
   for file in $(find / -name "HAHA" -type f); do
     mv "${file}" "/home/HAHA${i}"
     i=$((${i} + 1))
   done
   ```

   This iterates over all the `HAHA` files and moves each one to `/home/HAHAn`, where `n` again is an increasing number, starting with 1.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `while` loop:

```
i=1
find / -name 'HAHA' -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do mv "$file" "/home/${file##.*/}$((i++))"; done
```

Important here is `print0` option of `find` which (together with `-d ''` option of `read`) treats properly files with white spaces in their names. If you need to do such operation only once then first line which sets `i=1` is not needed since `bash` (and most of other shells) will simply created this variable automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Possible using GNU parallel

```
find / -name "HAHA" -type f | parallel 'echo mv {}
 ./dest-dir/{/}_`stat -c%i {}`

{/}  ............. returns dirname
{/.} ............. dirname with no extension
stat -c%i {} ..... gets the inode for each file "whic is unique"
```

OBS: I used `echo` for sake of testing, just remove it if it meets your needs